# Spring Boot: disable automatic conversion of numerics to boolean

Tags: spring-boot, rest, validation

I have a spring boot rest api and on post i have a json body with a boolean parameter, for example

```
{
    "param1": 101831470,
    "param2": 2.8,
    "param3": "lay",
    "param4": 80.02,
    "booleanParam": 2323231
}
```

the booleanParam is of type boolean in the DTO I use as a response body and the value  2323231 is converted to true, when the DTO is deserialised from the request.

Is there a simple configuration solution to prevent this.

We use spring boot 2.2.4.